# how to include script of variables in a class? undefined variable

Tags: php, class, include

got a script which has string variables that represent data fields like they are in the database. because this project is a complete mess this is a stage in cleaning it up and not having to rewrite the field name in numerous locations.

so one script `'DataKeys.php'` will have variables set to field names.

```
//results from query1
$keyField1  = 'field1';
$keyField2 = 'field2';
```

these two vars above is only a snippet of a much longer list.

I want to access this file and use these vars when I am formatting the data to be more friendly for the front end. this script is being accessed in a class however the fields, `$keyField1`, defined in the script is not being found in the class. I did have the actual string there but I think single access point would be best so when I make future changes I don't need search the whole project.

```
class DataFormatter {
    //put your code here
    public function __construct() {
        $documentRoot = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, "DOCUMENT_ROOT");
        include ($documentRoot . '/database/values/DataKeys.php');
    }

    public function cleanData($data){
        if (is_null($data) || empty($data)) 
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach($data as $row){
            $field1Value = $row[$keyField1];
            unset($row[$keyField1]);
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried moving the include outside the class definition.

```
$documentRoot = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, "DOCUMENT_ROOT");
include ($documentRoot . '/database/values/DataKeys.php');
```

The error that is being reported is :

```
Undefined variable: keyField1
```

**SOULTION**
Maybe not the optimal way but I took the include statement and placed it inside the function. The code above is just a demo of what I was trying to achieve not the actual code I am using.

Comment: Setting values in the scope of the constructor will not do anything as they will be gone as soon as the constructor finishes. If you really want to do it like this, you need to prepend all your lines with `public` (or `private`, etc.) and include it directly in the class itself. A slightly more decent solution would be to parse instead of include the file in your constructor to set to set the properties like `$this->keyField1 = ...`. But note that you probably have to rewrite everything as almost all variables in your example are out of scope / undefined / unused.

Comment: @jeroen Hmm so you're saying I cannot access these variables from an external php script and use them like a set of globals but only in the class that requests access to the file?

Comment: Not without declaring them global in every single method where you need them.

Comment: @jeroen okay so how should I declare those two fields global and access them in only in function of cleanData()?

Comment: If you only need them there, you should include the file there and your problem will be solved for this class.

Comment: That's the problem i don't think this will be the only location but I found a solution. For I'm trying to undo a whole site of mistakes that has grown into a mutant.

Answer (score 0):

the 2 variables are available just after the "include".
you can for example, put the 2 values in properties of the object

```
include ...;
$this->keyField1 = $keyField1;
$this->keyField2 = $keyField2;
```

Comment: Is there a way that I could have these variables you're adding into the DataFormatter placed in a separate file called DataKeys? So I can reference them from an external location. I just provided a template of a much longer list of field names.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign *DataKeys.php* to class member.

```
class DataFormatter {
    private $keyField1;
    private $keyField2;

    public function __construct($filename) {
        include $filename;
        $this->keyField1 = $keyField1;
        $this->keyField2 = $keyField2;
    }
}

$dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'DOCUMENT_ROOT') . '/database/values/DataKeys.php');
```

Comment: Is there a way that I could have these variables you're adding into the DataFormatter placed in a separate file called DataKeys? So I can reference them from an external location. I just provided a template of a much longer list of field names.